# Web Api timezone

Tags: c#, angular, webapi

I am having issues with time zones. My application use Angular and MVC web api for the back end. On my local machine everything works correctly because the server and the browser are in the same time zone. When I deploy it to the I get the incorrect date/time.

I have a save method:

```
    save(individualModel: IndividualModel, applicationId?: number) {
        let urlParams = new HttpParams();
        if (applicationId !== null && typeof applicationId !== 'undefined') {
            urlParams = urlParams.append('applicationId', applicationId.toString());
        }
        return this.http.post<IndividualModel>('api/Individual/Save', individualModel, {params: urlParams})
    }

export class IndividualModel {
    firstName: string;
    middleName: string;
    lastName: string;
    dob: Date;
    address: AddressModel;
    contact: ContactModel[];
    photos: PhotosModel;

    constructor(
        firstName?: string, 
        middleName?: string, 
        lastName?: string, 
        dob?: Date, 
        address?: AddressModel, 
        contact?: ContactModel[], 
        photos?: PhotosModel
    ) {
        this.firstName = firstName || null;
        this.middleName = middleName || null;
        this.lastName = lastName || null;
        this.dob = dob || null;
        this.address = address || new AddressModel();
        this.contact = contact || [];
        this.photos = photos || new PhotosModel();
        this.recordState = recordState || null;
    }
}
```

Back end web api

```
[HttpPost()]
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Save(Individual individualModel, int? applicationId = default(Integer?)
)
{
    try
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, await individualModel.Save(applicationId));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}

public virtual async Task<Individual> Save(int? applicationId = null, int? UserIdStamp = null)
{
    using (SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new SqlClient.SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CommandTimeout") != null)
                cmd.CommandTimeout = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CommandTimeout"));
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "[Individual_Save]";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithNullableValue("@Id", Id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithNullableValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithNullableValue("@MiddleName", MiddleName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithNullableValue("@LastName", LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithNullableValue("@UserIdStamp", UserIdStamp);
            if (DOB.HasValue)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithNullableValue("@DOB", DOB.Value.ToLocalTime());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithNullableValue("@ApplicationId", ApplicationId);
            await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();
            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while ((await reader.ReadAsync()))
                    Refresh(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Which does convert to UTC correctly for my time zone but the server is 3 hours behind me.
From server to web api 1987-04-25T00:00:00 which converts to 4/25/1987 12:00 AM
From my computer to server 1987-04-24T04:00:00.000Z which converts to 4/24/1987 9:00 PM.
Since this is the person date of birth it should not be converted based on the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Why are you calling `DOB.Value.ToLocalTime()`?

Why not just use the [DateTime.Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1) property?

Comment: I have solved this issue but DateTime.Date still caused an issue due to TimeZone being passed in. I ended up creating a custom Deserialization of the DateTime object that removed the T in the string, which made the time not shift for the TimeZone.